# Could anything cause blurry or fuzzy text when rendered to the html5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, fonts, html5-canvas

I am drawing text onto an html5 canvas. For some reason the rendered text is blurry or sometime fuzzy.

Here are two examples: [image] [image].

I am using `fillText(text, x, y)`.

I have placed log statements to count the number of times I call `fillText`. I am fairly certain that the `fillText` only gets called once.

Are there any other factors that could cause the html5 canvas to render fuzzy or blurry text?

The blur occurs with either standard browser fonts or google web fonts.

I should note that I have a 1920x1080 background image, with many divs on top of the canvas element.

Comment: @TiesonT., chromium on ubuntu; the same fonts render just fine in a textarea.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the blur on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y8mQP/3/

Comment: Hmm. The only suggestions I've seen anywhere say that your canvas can get fuzzy if you don't specify its dimensions, but you're doing that, so...

Comment: Do you rescale the canvas with CSS? When you use CSS to change the size of a canvas, it is drawn in the normal size internally and rescaled afterwards, which will make it blurry.

Comment: @Philipp, TiesonT., : I am setting the width and height of the canvas to 100% with css. But that should equal to 1920x1080 which is the dimensions of the parent. I am also setting the attributes of the element with the same coordinates. I can't tell if removing the 100% css dimension updates makes any changes--doesn't look like it does.

Comment: @Ramin: Setting a width and height with CSS is likely the reason why the canvas gets blurry.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent objects from being fuzzy in canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043827/how-can-i-prevent-objects-from-being-fuzzy-in-canvas)