# How can I prevent objects from being fuzzy in canvas?

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, html5-canvas

Currently, I'm doing a mini game which only has a box and a character.

The character can freely move around. I did so it moves 640px/second. The "formula" I use to get the pixels to move each frame is `((currentFrameTimeMs - lastFrameTimeMs) * pxPerSecond) / 1000`. Actual values are `((currentFrameTimeMs - lastFrameTimeMs) * 640) / 1000`. This effectively makes my character to move exactly 640px/s.

But the problem is that when moving, I see it as "fuzzy". I've checked out the FPS, and it's very far above 60, yet the image still looks fuzzy.

Is there any technique to remove that blurriness? I've played desktop games which have objects moving pretty fast, and they don't blur, so I suppose there's some trick for that.

Comment: We need more code...What code are you using to create/process your animation loop?  BTW, browsers only refresh the screen about 60 times per second so if your trying to refresh "very far above" 60fps then that will certainly cause your drawings to be blurry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

Problem was with FPS, they were under 60. I was using a wrong approach (with `requestAnimationFrame`, but wrong calculations).

Comment: this actually worked. I just had to manipulate my calcs for fps. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Round the result so your image will always be at an exact pixel index, rather than "between" pixels. If you don't round, the pixels of your image will be "spread" between pixels and might appear blurry.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. I tried `Math.round`, `Math.ceil` and `Math.floor`, but none of them work. Also, it's worth noting that my object only gets fuzzy when in movement, not while static.

Comment: Do you have a JSfiddle or something to show the problem?